# Server Error TypeError: Xt1.deprecate is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I am using next.js: 13.4.12 (app router) with next-auth: 4.22.3, prisma: 5.0.0, @next-auth/prisma-adapter: 1.0.7 in typescript.

I have also followed all the required boiler plate from the official documentation.

**this is my middleware.ts file**

```js
import withAdminsAuthentication from "./middleware/admin";
import withUserAuthentication from "./middleware/auth";
import { stackMiddlewares } from "./middleware/stackMiddlewares";

const middlewares = [withUserAuthentication, withAdminsAuthentication];
// stackMiddleware function chains the given list of middlewares
export default stackMiddlewares(middlewares);
```

**this is my middleware/auth.ts file**

```js
import type { MiddlewareFactory } from "./types";
import { options } from "@/lib/auth";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getUserByEmail } from "@/database/users";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

const authenticatedUsersOnlyRoutes: string[] = [
  // regex for routes that require authentication
];

const withUserAuthentication: MiddlewareFactory =
  (next) => async (request, event) => {
    const path = new URL(request.url).pathname;
    for (const route of authenticatedUsersOnlyRoutes) {
      const regex = new RegExp(route);
      console.log(regex, path);

      if (regex.test(path)) {
        // this line causes error. If I remove the getServerSession call there is no error
        const session = await getServerSession(options);

        if (session == null) {
          return NextResponse.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
        }
        const email = session.user?.email;
        if (email == null) {
          return NextResponse.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
        }

        const user = await getUserByEmail(email);

        if (user instanceof Error) {
          return NextResponse.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
        }

        request.user = user;
        return await next(request, event);
      }
    }
    return await next(request, event);
  };

export default withUserAuthentication;
```

**this is my @lib/auth.ts file where I export the next-auth options**

```js
import client from "@/database/client";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import type { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const clientId = process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET;

if (clientId == null || clientSecret == null) {
  throw new Error("Missing `Google Oauth` Credentials");
}

export const options: AuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      name: "Sign in with Google",
      clientId,
      clientSecret,
      httpOptions: {
        timeout: 20000,
      },
    }),
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(client),
};
```

**error stacktrace**

```
Server Error
TypeError: Xt1.deprecate is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
<unknown>
webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js (376)
deprecate
node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js (1:8533)
e
node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js (1:221)
Ri
node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js (5:258)
e
node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js (1:221)
Fi
node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js (7:9720)
Object.(middleware)/./node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js
file:///D:/Jk/Work/Recomm-new-prototype/.next/server/src/middleware.js (238:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///D:/Jk/Work/Recomm-new-prototype/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js (37:33)
fn
file:///D:/Jk/Work/Recomm-new-prototype/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js (268:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./src/database/client.ts (9:88)
Module.(middleware)/./src/database/client.ts
file:///D:/Jk/Work/Recomm-new-prototype/.next/server/src/middleware.js (1818:1)
```

**This was updated**

now I commented all the code in the middleware/auth.ts
but I still get the same error but now in middleware/admin.ts page

**here is the content in the middleware/admin.ts file**

```js
import type { MiddlewareFactory } from "./types";
import { getAdminByUserId } from "@/database/admin";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
const adminsOnlyRoutes: string[] = [
  // regex for routes that require admin authentication
];

const withAdminsAuthentication: MiddlewareFactory =
  (next) => async (request, event) => {
    const path = new URL(request.url).pathname;
    for (const route of adminsOnlyRoutes) {
      const regex = new RegExp(route);
      if (regex.test(path)) {
        // the route is in the list of routes that require authentication
        // validate if the user is authenticated
        if (request.user == null) {
          return NextResponse.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
        }
        const admin = getAdminByUserId(request.user.id);
        if (admin instanceof Error) {
          return NextResponse.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
        }
        return await next(request, event);
      }
    }
    // the route is not in the list of routes that require authentication
    return await next(request, event);
  };

export default withAdminsAuthentication;
```

by debugging line by line I found that the error was caused by getAdminByUserId which uses prisma.
it is confusing for me that I am getting the error even though the adminsOnlyRoutes array is empty

it seems like I cannot use prisma in the middleware.

can anyone explain me why and suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

**we cannot use prisma in the edge runtime yet.**

using prisma in edge run time leads to unexpected behaviors like this.

follow this Github [issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/18763) for more informations